# Case insensitive regex matching in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array with a list of power rangers colors, `rangers = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]`

I want to validate if a given argument matches the power rangers colors, but the problem is the argument may come in different case (uppercase, lowercase, mix).

Example:

```
def validate_rangers(color)
  rangers = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]
  rangers.grep(color).any?
end

validates_rangers("red") #=> true
```

but

```
validates_rangers("Red") #=> false. Needs to be true.
```

How can I use case insensitive grep?

Comment: to answer the actual question `i` is the case insensitive flag so the regex would be `/#{color}/i`  [example](https://repl.it/EqS4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The more idiomatic Ruby way of solving this problem looks like this:

```
# Define a constant that defines the colors once and once only.
RANGERS = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]

def validates_rangers(color)
  # Check against an arbitrary object that may or may not be a string,
  # and downcase it to match better.
  RANGERS.include?(color.to_s.downcase)
end
```

If you're doing this frequently you might want to use a `Set` to optimize performance:

```
RANGERS = Set.new(["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"])
```

That doesn't require any code changes, but lookups are considerably faster.

If you're intent on using a regular expression:

```
# Construct a case-insensitive regular expression that anchors to the
# beginning and end of the string \A...\z
RANGERS = Regexp.new(
  '\A(?:%s)\z' % Regexp.union("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"),
  Regexp::IGNORECASE
)

def validates_rangers(color)
  # Double negation returns true/false instead of MatchData
  !!RANGERS.match(color.to_s.downcase)
end

validates_rangers("Red")
# => true
validates_rangers("dred")
# => false
```

Comment: While this implementation seems a bit extreme for the given example it is definitely a worthwhile contribution and the addition of `to_s` to avoid data type issues offers an excellent addition.

Comment: Lovely regular expression construct.

Comment: Unless you already have an array, you could just use a literal, i.e. `RANGERS = /\A(?:red|blue|yellow|pink|black)\z/i`. And since it is a case insensitive regular expression, you can simply write `!!RANGERS.match(color)` (and [soon](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_preview3/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) `RANGERS.match?(color)`).

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, technically true, but sometimes it's nice to have that as an intermediate array so you can easily abstract that a bit more to read in from JSON, YAML, or some other form of config file with minimal changes. When I see a list like this, I see a list that will change fairly often.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the insensitive flag:

```
rangers.grep(/#{color}/i).any?
```

Since the flag makes the regex insensitive, it will match whatever case in `red`

**[Working demo](https://repl.it/EqS4/1)**

```
def validate_rangers(color)
  rangers = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]
  rangers.grep(/#{color}/i).any?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use downcase in the argument

```
def validate_rangers(color)
  rangers = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black"]
  rangers.include?(color.downcase)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.grep uses === for comparisons. To actually use regex as your comparison, you could change your array to be regexes instead of strings:

```
  rangers = [/red/, /blue/, /yellow/, /pink/, /black/]
```

and then in your comparison, use regex match (=~) instead of ====:

```
 rangers.map{|ranger| ranger =~ color }.any?
```

And to make the case insensitive comparison, you can add i to the end of your regex values. All together, it would look like this:

```
def validate_rangers(color)
  rangers = [/red/i, /blue/i, /yellow/i, /pink/i, /black/i]
  rangers.map{|ranger| ranger =~ color }.any?
end
```

Comment: `map` is redundant, `any?` takes block itself. Also, `rangers = %w|red blue yellow pink black|.map { |w| /#{w}/i }` looks less phpish.

Comment: That's really over the top there with multiple regular expressions. Hint: [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a regexp here:

```
def validate_rangers(color)
  rangers = %w|red blue yellow pink black|
  rangers.any? &color.downcase.method(:==)
end
```

Comment: Why not `find` or `include?`?

Comment: @tadman `find` is not technically a boolean response `nil` or first object. Although when used as a conditional it will still function as a boolean given ruby's truthy/falsey implementation. `include?` on the other hand I can agree with.

Comment: @tadman for no reason: there were already answers using `find`/`include?` methods, I showed up more elegant (read: less readable) one. I am almost sure, invoking the `proc` as above is faster.